# Добавление строк в файл MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, cmd, jar

Изучаю утилиту jar. Наткнулся на такой вопрос.
Набираю в cmd команду:

```
g:\classes>jar cfm Remainder.jar manifest.txt main remainder
```

Т.е. создаю новый jar-файл Remainder.jar в котором будут хранится пакеты main и remainder, а файл манифеста будет иметь строки из файла manifest.txt.

Вот что в файле manifest.txt:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: main.Main

Name: main
Sealed: true
```

Вот что получилось в файле MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_74 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: main.Main

Name: main
Sealed: true
```

Вроде бы всё так, как и должно быть. Идём дальше. Файл Remainder.jar я удаляю, и продолжаю дальше экспериментировать с утилитой:

```
g:\classes>jar cfm Remainder.jar m.txt main remainder
```

Файл m.txt:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: main.Main
```

Файл MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_74 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: main.Main
```

О нет! Я забыл загерметизировать пакет main! Не беда!

```
g:\classes>jar ufm Remainder.jar m2.txt
```

Т.е. добавляю в файл манифеста строки из файла m2.txt. Вот как выглядит файл m2.txt:

```
Name: main
Sealed: true
```

А вот что получаю в файле MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Sealed: true
Name: main
Created-By: 1.8.0_74 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: main.Main
```

Насколько я понимаю, это неверный файл манифеста.

Собственно вопрос: что я делаю не так?

UPD:

В небезызвестной книге Хорстманна "Java, библиотека профессионала" написано, что файл манифеста должен иметь такой вид:

```
Manifest-version: 1.0
строки описания архива

Name: Woozle.class
строки описания класса

Name: com/mycompany/mypackage
строки описания пакета
```

Полученный файл не удовлетворяет такой структуре, кроме того строка Sealed : true находится в главном разделе манифеста, хотя я планировал загерметизировать только пакет main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я сомневаюсь, что оракловская утилита может сгенерировать неправильный манифест. Попробуйте скормить ей дубликат, или ключ без значения. Если вы под неправильным вы имеете в виду порядок следования параметров, то все нормально.

> Versions:
>
> Manifest-Version and Signature-Version must be first, and in exactly
>   that case (so that they can be recognized easily as magic strings).
>   Other than that, the order of attributes within a main section is not
>   significant.
>
> Ordering:
>
> The order of individual manifest entries is not significant. The order
>   of individual signature entries is not significant, except that the
>   digests that get signed are in that order.

Это же просто набор опций в формате `ключ: значение`, записанных через LF. Если в манифесте не будет нужной информации, при попытке запуска вам выбросит исключение, в то же время неизвестные опции - игнорируются.

> Attributes which are not understood are ignored. Such attributes may
>   include implementation specific information used by applications.

[Ссылка на спецификацию](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jar/jar.html).

---

Манифест должен соответствовать спецификации, и он ей соответствует. Я не нашел где в документации к утилите `jar` явно сказано как модифицировать манифест так чтобы добавить новую секцию. Поэтому, методом тыка было установлено что для этого надо добавить пустую строку перед параметрами (в вашем случае в m2.txt). Получилось так:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_74 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: main.HelloWorld

Name: main
Sealed: true
```

Обычно такие задачи выполняются через системы сборки (maven, gradle, ant), где секции прописываются в явном виде. Я думаю `jar` только проверяет входные данные на синтаксические ошибки / дубликаты, и не занимается полной валидацией итогового манифеста. Поэтому если вы захотите в него нагадить, несомненно получится.

Comment: Я вопрос дополнил.

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: Дааа! Это работает! В общем, подытожив, чтобы добавить новую секцию, надо сделать первую строку добавляемого файла пустой. Иначе информация добавляется в главную секцию.
Банально и неинтересно :)
Спасибо огромное за ответ, и извините, что потратил ваше время на эту, как оказалось, ерунду :)